# Crystal Reports - adding same footer to multiple reports

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have multiple reports all of which require the same footer (company address, VAT no etc).

Is there a simple way to write this information once and apply it to all of my reports?

I thought I could do this with a simple subreport but this just seems to copy the subreport to the main report and any changes in the 'footer report' aren't reflected in the main report(s).

Thanks Ant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the "Re-Import When Opening" option in your subreport properties yet?  Once you select that, any changes you make to your "Common Footer Subreport" should be reflected when you open one of your main reports.

[image]

(It's grayed out in my pic since I chose a subreport that was native to the main report.  It didn't have a .rpt of it's own)

Comment: May you live a long and happy life - that worked beautifully - thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You want it the other way around.  Your main report has your common footer, and the unique details sections are subreports of that one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's quite what you're asking for, but you could create a template with that information in the footer, and then apply the template to each of your reports.